# ROW_NUMBER OR OTHER SEQUENCE DEPENDING ON DATE (SQL)

Tags: sql, hive, sequence, gaps-and-islands, row-number

I have a problem creating sequence using `row_number` and still can't deal with it.

I have a table

| bc | io | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1a | 11 | 2022-01-01 |
| 1a | 11 | 2022-01-02 |
| 1a | 12 | 2022-01-03 |
| 1a | 11 | 2022-01-04 |

When  I use simple `row_number` partitioned by `bc` and `io` and ordered by `date` I get this result

| bc | io | date | rn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1a | 11 | 2022-01-01 | 1 |
| 1a | 11 | 2022-01-02 | 2 |
| 1a | 12 | 2022-01-03 | 1 |
| 1a | 11 | 2022-01-04 | 3 |

But I need this result, when `io` changes, next `io`, that has met before already, should start with 1

| bc | io | date | rn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1a | 11 | 2022-01-01 | 1 |
| 1a | 11 | 2022-01-02 | 2 |
| 1a | 12 | 2022-01-03 | 1 |
| 1a | 11 | 2022-01-04 | 1 |

I tried to use this sql, but it is not correct

```
select tt.*,row_number() over(partition by tt.bc,tt.io order by tt.date ) as rn
from (
    select '1a' as bc, 11 as io, '2021-01-01' as date
    union all
    select '1a' as bc, 11 as io, '2021-01-02' as date
    union all
    select '1a' as bc, 12 as io, '2021-01-03' as date
    union all
    select '1a' as bc, 11 as io, '2021-01-04' as date
) as tt
```

Comment: Does this logic change in `row_number` affects the `bc` column as well, or just `io`? I mean, if `bc` changes should it "reset" the `rn`?

Comment: Is it possible to have more than one record for the same `bc` and `date` with different `io`?

Comment: @andexte it affects just `io`, and it is not possible to have same `date`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common gaps-and-islands problem: group consecutive attribute values per key (given some "time-like" dimension). The approach is this:

- Calculate `row_number` per key ordered by time dimentsion.
- Calculate `row_number` per key and attributes of interest ordered by time dimension.
- Find their difference - this would group consecutive same values of attributes (the second `row_number` resets to 1 on a change of some attribute and the difference increases).

Below is a query:

```
with src as (
    select inline(array(
      struct('1a', 11, date '2022-01-01'),
      struct('1a', 11, date '2022-01-02'),
      struct('1a', 12, date '2022-01-03'),
      struct('1a', 11, date '2022-01-04')
    )) as (bc, io, dt)
)
, prepared as (
  select
    src.*
    /*Partition by keys*/
    , row_number() over(partition by bc order by dt asc)
        /*Partition by keys AND attributes to track changes and create groups*/
      - row_number() over(partition by bc, io order by dt asc) as rn_diff
  from src
)
select
  bc, io, dt
  /*Partition by keys AND attributes to track changes AND group number*/
  , row_number() over(partition by bc, io, rn_diff order by dt asc) as rn
from prepared
order by dt asc
```

| bc | io | dt | rn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1a | 11 | 2022-01-01 | 1 |
| 1a | 11 | 2022-01-02 | 2 |
| 1a | 12 | 2022-01-03 | 1 |
| 1a | 11 | 2022-01-04 | 1 |

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/PJTdQ4d8) based on Postgres (with more attributes added).

Comment: It can produce incorrect output on bigger input: https://dbfiddle.uk/jPMBxpSJ Attention to the last row.

Comment: @markalex Thank you, I've missed key column and an attributes in the final `partition by`. Fixed

Answer (score 0):

You can manually compare rows with "previous" ones and create an indicator of change based on it. Later summation of this indicator will provide you partition number, identifying uninterrupted blocks.

And this partition number could be used in partition clause of you `row_number`.

```sql
with tt as (
    select '1a' as bc, 11 as io, '2021-01-01' as date
    union all
    select '1a' as bc, 11 as io, '2021-01-02' as date
    union all
    select '1a' as bc, 12 as io, '2021-01-03' as date
    union all
    select '1a' as bc, 11 as io, '2021-01-04' as date
), t2 as(
  select 
    tt.*,
    case when bc = lag(bc) over (order by date) and io = lag(io) over (order by date) then 0 else 1 end ind
  from tt
), t3 as (
  select 
    t2.*, 
    sum(ind) over ( order by date) pid 
  from t2
)
select 
  bc,
  io, 
  date, 
  row_number() over (partition by pid order by date) rn
from t3
```

Demo (in MySQL) [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/SrnOFL-_).

---

**EDIT:** to ignore changes of `bc` disregard part of case condition mentioning `bc`:

```sql
with tt as (
    select '1a' as bc, 11 as io, '2021-01-01' as date
    union all
    select '1b' as bc, 11 as io, '2021-01-02' as date
    union all
    select '1a' as bc, 12 as io, '2021-01-03' as date
    union all
    select '1a' as bc, 11 as io, '2021-01-04' as date
), t2 as(
  select 
    tt.*,
    case when io = lag(io) over (order by date) then 0 else 1 end ind
  from tt
), t3 as (
  select 
    t2.*, 
    sum(ind) over ( order by date) pid 
  from t2
)
select 
  bc,
  io, 
  date, 
  row_number() over (partition by pid order by date) rn
from t3
```

Demo in MySQL [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/ecsQpbTb).

Comment: It can provide incorrect output if the `bc` column changes. Please check the last 3 columns of this example. https://dbfiddle.uk/0zousjyt

Comment: @andexte, sorry, missed comment of OP about it. Added query for that case.